# Biblatex: website citation is italicized and uses title instead of author when removing "n.d."

Tags: latex, citations, biblatex

I'm trying to cite a website using the authoryear style with BibLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@online{nanopore,
    author    = "{Oxford Nanopore Technologies}",
    title     = "Oxford Nanopore Technologies Github",
    url       = "https://github.com/nanoporetech"
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
sorting=nyt,
citestyle=authoryear,
maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}

\parencite{nanopore}

\end{document}
```

This gives me

[image: This citation]

which is fine except I want to remove the "n.d.", so then I do this to remove it:

```
\DeclareLabeldate[online]{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \field{urldate}
}
```

And then my citation changes, so 1) it prints the title instead of the author, and 2) the citation is italicizes (which is probably because it's printing the title instead of author).

[image: Italicized citation using title instead of author]

Any idea why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: [image: Link to picture with space added] for @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the translation for "n.d." for the online type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@online{nanopore,
    author    = "{Oxford Nanopore Technologies}",
    title     = "Oxford Nanopore Technologies Github",
    url       = "https://github.com/nanoporetech"
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
sorting=nyt,
citestyle=authoryear,
maxbibnames=99,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
nodate = {\ifboolexpr{test{\ifentrytype{online}}}{\unspace}{n\adddot d\adddot}},
}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}

\parencite{nanopore}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works, but weirdly it seems to introduce a space between the last word and the end parenthesis in the citation, but in your example it doesn't seem to?

Comment: @AlexanderAndersen Can you make a minimal working example that shows the whitespace. In my example I introduced a negative space to compensate for the additional space.

Comment: I copy pasted your script and made no changes at all, but get a space. (I'm not sure if it's possible to add a picture to a comment, but I added it at the bottom of my post. EDIT: I get an error "Undefined control sequence" with description "<argument> \negthickspace", so I guess it doesn't understand it. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your tex distribution is outdated? Try with `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{nodate = {\ifboolexpr{test{\ifentrytype{online}}}{\hskip-.2777em}{n\adddot d\adddot}}}` or show your .log file

Comment: That worked! I'm using Overleaf, so I guess they run with an older version? Thanks a lot for helping me out. I'm marking this as solved.

Comment: @AlexanderAndersen Yes, overleaf is usually a year or so behind.

Comment: @AlexanderAndersen I found a cleaner solution without this hack. Can you check again?

Comment: That works as well. Nice job!